# How to Input a Discount Price in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, syntax, e-commerce

The Discount field does not register 
(discount is supposed to subtract from Grand Total)(*check discount sample*)

check the the [jsfiddle click here](http://jsfiddle.net/infinityswift19/enm4yhdk/13/)

I want it to act like this picture. (with the discount being manually inputed)   http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2013/02/07/article-2275089-17694138000005DC-460_634x497.jpg

Javascript

```
function recordToFilename() {
        var input = document.getElementById('discountvalue'),
    discount12 = input.value;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your button to

```
<input type="button" onclick="recordToFilename();" value="Submit Discount"  />
```

And function

```
function recordToFilename() {
            var input = document.getElementById('discount'),
        discount12 = input.value;

alert (discount12);
}
```

Comment: couldnt seem to get that to work . Did u try it in [jsfiddle click here](http://jsfiddle.net/infinityswift19/enm4yhdk/12/)

Comment: yes. It is working, alert is firing with correct discount value. replace input field with this. replace javascript function. It should work. What browser are you checking

Comment: yes the alert function works thanks. I need the discount function to work with code. Not sure why it is not. I believe I am using the correct id's. I dont know. I want it to act like this picture.(with the discount being manually inputed) (http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2013/02/07/article-2275089-17694138000005DC-460_634x497.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 id="discount". Change one of the id and the there is no problem to register the input value to discount12.

Put this line `document.getElementById('discounts').innerHTML = "<strong>Discount </strong>: $" + (salesTotal * 0.14 + salesTotal - discount12).toFixed(2);` 
in your `recordToFilename()` method and make sure your variable is chage to `discount12` not `discount`